# Install ElasticBundle in Symfony2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony-2.1

I am using Symfony 2.1 for my project. In my project elasticsearch will be used for my search engine. I found that Elastica is a greate PHP client for elasticsearch. ElasticBundle is a wrapper of Elastica for symfony2.0 . I follow the step by step offical doc https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle#readme . But It seems like the doc is outdated. I think it was for symfony2. I try to intergrate with symfony2.1 without success. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did like that, add line:

```
//composer.json
...
"require": {
    ...
    "exercise/elastica-bundle": "dev-master",
}
...
```

Then I run `php composer.phar update`. And then add line:

```
//app/AppKernel.php
...
    new FOQ\ElasticaBundle\FOQElasticaBundle(),
...
```

Comment: I found the same way a few days ago. It is very straight forward. anyway thanks.